# Tooltips don't show with (some) touchscreens

Tags: feature-request, support, tooltips, touch-screen

I've been visiting SO for a while now on my Surface Pro 3. The Surface Pen is a stylus supposed to act like a mouse, so when hovering on an element, tooltips should show.

But this doesn't appear to work on Stack Exchange sites. The tooltips do show when I use my mouse, so it's not an issue with the site's rendering on my computer.

**Testing:**

- Pen's hover ability works on other sites.
- SO on IE11 (standard version) and Chrome were both unsuccessful with the Surface Pen.
- IE11 *touch-calibrated* version works with the Pen.

Perhaps, there should be added support for special touchscreen styli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent update fixed this?  Tooltips are now showing, hurray!